# Rails 4 - jQuery File Upload - SyntaxError: Unexpected token $

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-file-upload

I am having an issue with jQuery File Upload and Rails 4.  Everything appears to be working except **one thing!**  The files are successfully uploaded and data is successfully posted to the database.  But, I get the following error upon uploading or "creating":

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token $
```

**My guess:**  I think it has something to do with it wanting to receive JSON back, but I don't know how to achieve this or where to put it.  Any help would be great!

Here is what I have:

## create.js.erb

```
<% if @choice.new_record? %>
   alert("Failed to upload image: <%= j @choice.errors.full_messages.join(', ').html_safe      %>");
 <% else %>
  $("#paintings").append("<%= j render(@choice) %>");
 <% end %>
```

## index.html.erb

```
  <h1>Choices Gallery</h1>

<div id="paintings">
  <%= render @choices %>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Upload file</h2>
  <%= form_for Choice.new, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload"  } do |f| %>
<!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
<div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
  <div class="span7">
    <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
      <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
      <span>Add files...</span>
      <%= f.file_field :image, multiple: true, name: "choice[image]" %>
    </span>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
      <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
      <span>Start upload</span>
    </button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
      <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
      <span>Cancel upload</span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
      <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
      <span>Delete</span>
    </button>
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
  </div>
  <div class="span5">
    <!-- The global progress bar -->
    <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active fade">
      <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- The loading indicator is shown during image processing -->
<div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
<br>
<!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
<table class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody>
</table>
```

## choices_controller.rb

```
 class ChoicesController < ApplicationController
def index
  @choices = Choice.all
end

def show
  @choice = Choice.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @choice = Choice.new
end

def create
  @choice = Choice.create(choice_params)
end
end
```

**Update #1**
First, I forgot to mention that I am using CarrierWave.  Second, here is what the console is giving back: (you can see it adds to the DB no problem.  There just seems to be an error with AFTER it's uploaded).

```
Started POST "/choices" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-15 15:07:45 -0700
Processing by ChoicesController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"iKxDDhTAbu/hY/QqEk9jXr9NJltIQmGWu6tUZEMe7pM=", "choice"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe3f2c50818 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/z6/c199lpm13492b758r5xx0ngm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130815-28015-ngm6w2>, @original_filename="speech_teacher.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"choice[image]\"; filename=\"speech_teacher.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (26.4ms)  INSERT INTO `choices` (`created_at`, `image`, `name`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2013-08-15 22:07:45', 'speech_teacher.jpg', 'Speech Teacher', '2013-08-15 22:07:45')
(0.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/choices
Completed 302 Found in 75ms (ActiveRecord: 27.0ms)


Started GET "/choices" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-15 15:07:45 -0700
Processing by ChoicesController#index as JSON
Choice Load (1.7ms)  SELECT `choices`.* FROM `choices`
Rendered choices/_choice.html.erb (2.5ms)
Rendered choices/index.html.erb within layouts/application (13.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 109ms (Views: 106.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

Comment: Does it give you a line number with the error?

Comment: Hi @Vigrant, thanks for your reply.  The error shows up in the jQuery-File-Upload error div: <span class="label label-important">Error</span>.  There is nothing more to the error that I can see. I checked in the server console, and no errors were reported there.

Comment: Hey @Vigrant, I went ahead and updated the post to see if that helps.  Thanks.

Comment: what does your sprockets manifest (`application.js`) look like? do you `require` jquery there?

Comment: Yes, jquery is being included (I can see it in the source code).  Also, the jquery-file-upload is firing and working fine, so I know it's not that.  I think it has something to do with jquery-file-upload requiring a JSON response, but I am not sure how to do so.

Comment: yes, that'd have been my next point. the console output up there tells us it is rendering json because the request wants json. the [basic example](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html) also uses json. i guess you'll have to use [jquery file upload callbacks](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#callback-options) to do something after things finished.